# git checkout <branch> <file path> does not match what is on <branch>

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-checkout

I am having a confusing issue with `git`

On `main/development` I have a file that has the most up-to-date changes of `UsersTable.tsx`

On my working branch `chore/add-linting` I am a few commits ahead, but I want to pull the latest code of `UsersTable.tsx` from `main/development`.

I performed:

```sh
$ git pull origin main/development

# oh no, I have a couple merge conflicts

# I want this file to be whatever is exactly on `main/development`
$ git checkout main/development path/to/UsersTable.tsx

Updated 1 path from f59fed63
```

However, the file is NOT what is `main/development`! The version that it checked out for me is still behind `main/development` and has old code.

What is going on here? I did `git fetch` and the `git pull`.

Comment: You needed to use the name `origin/main/development` here, just as with `git restore`. But `git restore` is better *because* it is *less powerful:* it's easier to do the wrong thing with `git checkout` by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to restore one file, you might consider using the command [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) instead of the [old and confusing `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

In your case:

```sh
git fetch
git restore -SW -s origin/main/development -- path/to/UsersTable.tsx
```

That way, you don't pull, meaning do not merge `origin/main/development` to `chore/add-linting`, so you don't have any merge conflict to manager.

You just restore one file content from a version of another branch.